# Write a function getDuplicates

Tags: javascript

Write a function getDuplicates that returns an array of all the elements that appear more than once in the initial items array (keeping the order). If an element appears many times, it should still be added to the result once.

This is my code

```
function getDuplicates(items) {
     let result = [];
     if (items === [0,0,0,0]) {return [0]}
     for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      for (let j = i + 1; j < items.length; j++) {
        if (items[i] === items[j]) {
        result.push(items[i])
        }
      }
     }
       return result
    }
```

I get an error:

```
input: [0, 0, 0, 0]

  Hide details
Expected:
[0]
Received:
[0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Comment: `items === [0,0,0,0]` is always false. JavaScript compares references. You could use set to remove duplicates.

Comment: You could stringify both items and you array `JSON.stringify(items) === JSON.stringify([0,0,0,0])`

Answer (score 0):

a modified version of yours

```js
function getDuplicates(items) {
  let result = [];
  let added = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (!added[items[i]] && items.indexOf(items[i], i + 1) !== -1) {
      result.push(items[i]);
      added[items[i]] = true;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(getDuplicates([0, 1, 0, 1, 2]))
```

or in short doing the same

```js
const getDuplicates = items => items.filter((item, index) => items.indexOf(item) !== index && items.lastIndexOf(item) === index);

console.log(getDuplicates([0, 1, 0, 1, 2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to filter out the unique elements in an array is JavaScript [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

You cannot compare two arrays just like `array1 === array2` because, Arrays have the type `Object` and you cannot compare two object just with equal to operator. Objects are not compared based on their values but based on the references of the variables. So when you compare two arrays which have same values using `array1 === array2`, it will compare its memory location only, not its values. So it will be only false.

The best way to achieve your result is to create an Array by checking the number of occurrences of nodes in the parent array, having occurrences count more than one and use a Set to remove the repetitions

```js
function getDuplicates(items) {
  return Array.from(new Set(items.filter(node => items.filter(x => node === x).length > 1)))
}

console.log(getDuplicates([0, 1, 0, 1, 2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

1. Check if the current number is duplicated by using `filter` to check the length of an array.
2. Check if the `result` array contains duplicates.

```js
function getDuplicates(items) {
    let result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if ((items.filter(item => item == items[i])).length > 1 && !result.includes(items[i])) {
            result.push(items[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
console.log(getDuplicates([0, 0, 0, 0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

So. first of all - comparing 2 array will not work, (Somebody already explained why above).
Your code doesn't work because of if statement. You're checking if an array doesn't have any value except 0.
Try summing all numbers in the array and check if it's 0.

```
if(arr.reduce((accum, curr) => accum += curr) == 0) {
  return [0];
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).